# How do I print a function return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

My code looks like this:

```
from random import randint

Item = randint(1, 10)

def ItemName(Item):
if Item == 1:
return Hat
elif Item == 2:
return Gloves
elif Item == 3:
return Scarf
elif Item == 4:
return Top
elif Item == 5:
return Pants
elif Item == 6:
return Shoes
elif Item == 7:
return Socks
elif Item == 8:
return Sunglasses
elif Item == 9:
return Bag
else:
return Jacket

print (ItemName)
```

I expect the program to print one of the possible values it could return. Like, 'hat', or 'socks', or 'bag'. Instead, I get "" or some other variant of complete gibberish.

Comment: You have to call the function `ItemName` and pass the parameter to it. You did neither.

Comment: Also you are returning undefined variables. If you want to print it out, you need to `return "Hat"`

Comment: Somehow unrelated to the topic: Consider to use a list/dictionary instead of creating sooo much `elif`.

Answer (score 3):

You never invoked the function with the Item, you just printed the Function. you have many undefined variables, from the context I think it should be a string
Try the following

```
    from random import randint 

    Item = randint(1, 10)

    def ItemName(Item):
        if Item == 1:
            return "Hat"
        elif Item == 2:
            return "Gloves"
        elif Item == 3:
            return "Scarf"
        elif Item == 4:
            return "Top"
        elif Item == 5:
            return "Pants"
        elif Item == 6:
            return "Shoes"
        elif Item == 7:
            return "Socks"
        elif Item == 8:
            return "Sunglasses"
        elif Item == 9:
            return "Bag"
        else:
            return "Jacket"

    print (ItemName(Item))
```

Answer (score 2):

The items within the function must be defined as strings.  Don't forget to include the parameters when calling functions.

Hope this helps!

Refactored Code:

```
from random import randint

item = randint(0, 9)

def itemName(item):
    arr = ["Hat", "Gloves", "Scarf", "Top",
           "Pants", "Shoes", "Socks", "Sunglasses", "Bag", "Jacket"]
    return(arr[item])

print(itemName(item))
```

Comment: I would move the declaration after the function to avoid confusion with scope (not really a problem with this code but just good practice).

Answer (score 2):

## Functions in Python

To explain what you have done wrong you need a comprehensive understanding of functions.

When you define the function i.e.

```
def ItemName(item)
```

`ItemName` is the name of the function, and `item` inside the brackets is the argument. The **argument/parameter** is simply a variable that can be used within the scope of the code.

For instance given a simple function:

```
def example(arg):
   return argument
```

you pass in the argument `arg`, which is anything you pass the function when it is invoked. To properly call/invoke a function:

```
foo = example('I just called a function!')
```

This will pass into the function the string `'I just called a function!'`. On the function call, it returns the string that you passes into it. To print the string simply print the return of the function:

```
print(foo)

>>> I just called a function!
```

To fix your code you simply need to pass Items into ItemName like such:

```
print(ItemName(item))
```

---

## A Better Approach

I have noticed your code is a bit repetitive and in effect unreadable. A better approach to solving the problem would involve using list.

```
import random

ITEMS = ["Hat", "Gloves", "Scarf", "Top", "Pants", "Shoes", "Socks", 
         "Sunglasses", "Bag"]

def itemNames(index):
   if index < len(items):
       return items[index]
   return 'Jacket'

print(itemNames(random.randint(1,9), items))
```

The function above will print the index of items list, for instance, if you were to pass in 0, the function would get the first element in the list `"Hat"`.

Although this way is quite slow as every time you call the function is has to look through each item until it matches the index you provided. A More efficient solution would be to use dictionaries like `@Onyambu's` solution.

### Anonymous Functions

If you want a quick one liner you could also consider an anonymous function, or lambda expression as they are called in python

```
arr_num = lambda x: arr[x] if x < len(arr) else "Jacket"
print(arr_num(random.randint(0, 9))
```

---

## Styling

Also your variable and function names shouldn't be capitalised, this is reserved for classes. I would advice you take a brief look at the [PEP8 Styling Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Hope this has helped you gain a basic understanding of function use in python, and fixed your code :)

Answer (score 0):

Even better:

```
from random import randint
item = randint(0, 9)
def itemName(item):
    l=["Hat", "Gloves", "Scarf", "Top", "Pants", "Shoes", "Socks", "Sunglasses", "Bag", "Jacket"]
    try:return l[item]
    except:return 'index not in list'
print(itemName(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the use of a dictionary, where you call the value by a key:

```
  from random import randint
  xx =["Hat", "Gloves", "Scarf", "Top", "Pants", "Shoes", "Socks", "Sunglasses", "Bag", "Jacket"]

  dict(zip(range(1,len(xx)+1),xx)).get(randint(1,11))
```

Every time you run the code above you will get a different value.

Or you can do:

```
 Item =randint(1,11)
 vv = dict(zip(range(1,len(xx)+1),xx))
 vv.get(Item)
```

This is exactly the same as the line of code above